# Use scipy.optimize.root on a numpy array with additional arguments

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, levenberg-marquardt

Given the optimization problem (1) as depicted below where `p_i`, `p'_i` and `w_ji` are given for `i=0,...,6889`, I want to use the Levenberg-Marquardt method to find an optimal solution for `R_j` and `v_j` using `scipy.optimize.root` (I'm open to any other suggestions).

[image: Imgur]

However, I don't know how to set up the callable function that needs to be passed to `root`. So far, all I have is this which is obviously wrong.

```
def fun(x, (old_points, new_points, weights, n_joints)):
    """
    :param x: variable to optimize. It is supposed to encapsulate R and v from (1)
    :param old_points: original vertex positions, (6890,3) numpy array
    :param new_points: transformed vertex positions, (6890,3) numpy array
    :param weights: weight matrix obtained from spectral clustering, (n_joints, 6890) numpy array
    :param n_joints: number of joints
    :return: non-linear cost function to find the root of
    """
    # Extract rotations and offsets
    R = np.array([(np.array(x[j * 15:j * 15 + 9]).reshape(3, 3)) for j in range(n_joints)])
    v = np.array([(np.array(x[j * 15 + 9:j * 15 + 12])) for j in range(n_joints)])

    # Use equation (1) for the non-linear pass.
    # R_j p_i
    Rp = np.einsum('jkl,il', x, old_points) # x shall replace R
    # w_ji (Rp_ij + v_j)
    wRpv = np.einsum('ji,ijk->ik', weights, Rp + x) # x shall replace v

    # Set up a non-linear cost function, then compute the squared norm.
    d = new_points - wRpv
    result = np.einsum('ik,ik', d, d)

    return result
```

EDIT: This is now the correct result.

Comment: Which of these are you trying to optimize `x, old_points, new_points, weights, rv, n_joints`? Make a closure over the others.

Comment: I'm trying to optimize `x` which I haven't incorporated into the problem yet as I don't know how. From my understanding, `R_j` and `v_j` in (1) are `x`, and `rv` from the code is my initial guess.

Comment: So `x` is the only unknown?

Comment: Yes. Also, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use your original `fun` (but give it a better name)

```
def fun(x, (old_points, new_points, weights, n_joints)):
    """
    :param x: variable to optimize. It is supposed to encapsulate R and v from (1)
    :param old_points: original vertex positions, (6890,3) numpy array
    :param new_points: transformed vertex positions, (6890,3) numpy array
    :param weights: weight matrix obtained from spectral clustering, (n_joints, 6890) numpy array
    :param n_joints: number of joints
    :return: non-linear cost function to find the root of
    """
    # Extract rotations and offsets
    R = np.array([(np.array(x[j * 15:j * 15 + 9]).reshape(3, 3)) for j in range(n_joints)])
    v = np.array([(np.array(x[j * 15 + 9:j * 15 + 12])) for j in range(n_joints)])

    # Use equation (1) for the non-linear pass.
    # R_j p_i
    Rp = np.einsum('jkl,il', x, old_points) # x shall replace R
    # w_ji (Rp_ij + v_j)
    wRpv = np.einsum('ji,ijk->ik', weights, Rp + x) # x shall replace v

    # Set up a non-linear cost function, then compute the squared norm.
    d = new_points - wRpv
    result = np.einsum('ik,ik', d, d)

    return result
```

make a closure on it so that it takes a single input (the variable you are solving):

```
old_points = ...
new_points = ...
weights = ...
rv = ...
n_joints = ...
def cont_function(x):
    return fun(x, old_points, new_points, weights, rv, n_joints)
```

now try use `cost_function` in `roots`

Comment: Thank you but I don't quite see how this should work as you don't use `x` anywhere in `fun` and `result` is simply a numpy float array? Maybe I didn't explain my problem well enough, therefore I edited my post again to point it out.

Comment: @Rani just replace `fun` with your updated code, `cost_function` remains untouched.

Comment: I got it now, thank you for your effort! All I had to do was replacing `rv` by `x`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really read your code so I wasn't sure what rv and x etc were. But the principle is just to create a closure so that you pass `roots` a function that takes a single variable. You can even use a lambda function if you prefer not to create `cots_function` outside of `roots`.

Comment: Instead of defining the new function `cost_function`, you can use `functools.partial` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).
Partial is exactly defined for this task.